# Can I bounce the ball after it is rolling in Basketball?

Tags: basketball

In Basketball, let's say I am dribbling and involuntarily the ball hit my hand wrongly and starts rolling (not bouncing). If I tap it from above and get it bouncing again, is that a double dribble? According to the links below it seems that re-bouncing a rolling ball is allowed.

Also, does it make a difference if the ball is rolling or just sitting on the floor when I hit it to make it bounce again?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dribble

NBA violations
http://official.nba.com/rule-no-10-violations-and-penalties/

Dribble definition in NBA
http://official.nba.com/rule-no-4-definitions/#Dribble

FIBA says
http://www.fiba.basketball/documents/official-basketball-rules.pdf

> Art. 24 Dribbling
>   24.1 Definition
>
> 24.1.1 A dribble is the movement of a live ball caused by a player in control of that ball who throws, taps, rolls or bounces the ball on
>   the floor.
>
> 24.1.2 A dribble starts when a player, having gained control of a live ball on the playing court throws, taps, rolls or bounces it on the
>   floor and touches it again before it touches another player.
>
> A dribble ends when the player touches the ball with both hands
>   simultaneously or permits the ball to come to rest in one or both
>   hands. During a dribble the ball may be thrown into the air provided
>   the ball touches the floor or another player before the player who
>   threw it touches it again with his hand. There is no limit to the
>   number of steps a player may take when the ball is not in contact with
>   his hand.

and about Double Dribble:

> 24.2 Rule A player shall not dribble for a second time after his first dribble has ended unless between the 2 dribbles he has lost control of
>   a live ball on the playing court because of: • A shot for a field
>   goal. • A touch of the ball by an opponent. • A pass or fumble that
>   has touched or been touched by another player.

Reading the definitions above, it seems to me that when the ball is rolling on the floor (without bouncing) the dribble has not ended, therefore it wouldn't be double dribble to tap it and get it bouncing again

Answer (score 1):

To my experiences, it is not considered to be a double dribble according the FIBA rules. I have this action being performed several times during a game when I was coaching. None of the referees did call a foul.

A more objective explanation is this: The rolling of the ball is also being considered as being part of the first dribble, so resuming the dribble without deliberately stopping the ball will not stop the dribble. Even if the ball has stopped rolling, the payer hasn't stopped the ball with its hands.